# Find index of item in group of 4 lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pycharm

Following is a function in python to find index of a input in group of 4.

```py
def mapping(inp_rate=[],inp_rssi=[]):
    a1=[6.5,13.0,19.5,26.0,39.0,52.0,58.5,65.0]`
    a11=[7.2,14.4,21.7,28.9,43.3,57.8,65.0,72.2]
    a2=[13.0,26.0,39.0,52.0,78.0,104.0,117.0,130.0]
    a22=[14.4,28.9,43.3,57.8,86.7,115.6,130,144.4]
    result_list = []
    print inp_rate
    for value in inp_rate:
        if value in a1:
            result_list.append(a1.index(value))
        elif value in a11:
            result_list.append(a11.index(value))
        elif value in a2:
            result_list.append(a2.index(value))
        elif value in a22:
            result_list.append(a22.index(value))
        else:
            result_list.append(0)
        print(result_list)
```

output is as below:

```
['65.0', '144.4', '72.2', '72.2']
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As the list items are present in a1,a11,a2,a22, cant understand why the index  are 0!

Comment: Are those groups always of the same length? What if an element from `inp_rate` is not found in any of the groups?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: please see the updated ques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you wanted the index, but 65 has an index of 7 in the `a1` list. If you want the actual place (where the first item of a list is 1 and not 0) then just add one to the value getting appended to the list.

Also, I've added a print statement when a value isn't in any list, as @Chris mentioned.

```
a1 = [6.5, 13, 19.5, 26, 39, 52, 58.5, 65]
a11 = [7.2, 14.4, 21.7, 28.9, 43.3, 57.8, 65, 72.2]
a2 = [13, 26, 39, 52, 78, 104, 117, 130]
a22 = [14.4, 28.9, 43.3, 57.8, 86.7, 115.6, 130, 144.4]

inp_rate = [65, 72.2, 72.2, 39, 72.2, 144.4, 78, 13, 72.2, 104, 6.5]

result_list = []

for value in inp_rate:
    if value in a1:
        result_list.append(a1.index(value))
    elif value in a11:
        result_list.append(a11.index(value))
    elif value in a2:
        result_list.append(a2.index(value))
    elif value in a22:
        result_list.append(a22.index(value))
    else:
        print("{} cannot be found".format(value))

print(result_list)
```

This prints

```
[7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 1, 7, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wheter it is the most efficent way, but my approach would be:

At first, I'd put the arrays in a tuple for beeing able iterating through them:

```
arr = (a1, a11, a2, a22)
```

The next step would be iterating through your inputs and the arrays, checking wheter the number is in the array and then appending the index to a list for the outputs:

```
out = []
for i in inp_rate:
    for j in arr:
        if i in j:
            output.append(j.index(i))
```

And as you start counting by 1 and not by 0, you need to add 1 in the append method.

Comment: `@jkoehl` what if the element is not found in the lists?

Comment: in this implementation, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = a1 + a11 + a2 + a22
result = [x.index(i)%8+1 if i in x else -1 for i in inp_rate]
result
```

Comment: Since all four lists have 8 elements, I concatenate them. Find the index and then divide it by 8 and get the remainder and plus 1. This method do not work if the four lists are of different size.

Comment: You should add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
list1 = [ a1,a11,a2,a22]

for i in inp_rate:
    c = 0
    for j in list1:
        if i in j:
            c+=1
            print(j.index(i),i,j,c)
            if c == 1 :
                result_list.append(j.index(i)+1)
```

output:

result_list = [8, 8, 8, 5, 8, 8, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1]

Answer (score 0):

need to put the lists as follows and it worked.

```
a1=['6.5','13.0','19.5','26.0','39.0','52.0','58.5','65.0']
a11=['7.2','14.4','21.7','28.9','43.3','57.8','65.0','72.2']
a2=['13.0','26.0','39.0','52.0','78.0','104.0','117.0','130.0']
a22=['14.4','28.9','43.3','57.8','86.7','115.6','130.0','144.4']
```